# Git - Commit in editor, but no editor is opening

Tags: git

I am simply trying to do a `git pull` which I have done hundreds of times. For some reason, this time it is showing me this in the console

```
# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
```

however, nothing opens for me to enter this commit message. I believe something like Vim or whatever should open (which I have never used) but I am at a stalemate trying to pull code.

I see this in my `git config`

`core.editor=vi`

What can I do? Can I enter said commit message some other way? I am using Mac OSX Lion.

Comment: Are you trying to pull onto a branch on which you have made commits?  Do you really want to do that?  It looks in your question like `vi` *did* start.

Comment: If you don't understand vi, set your editor to BBEdit or freeware TextWrangler. Works very well with git.

Comment: I have no idea how to use vi. I do have TextWrangler. If TextWrangler exists in my Applications folder on Mac OSX, how do I set it as my editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the editor, do:

```
git config --global core.editor TextWrangler
```

(replace TextWrangler with the exact command to call your editor, preferably with the full path).

This changes the configuration for your account (all `git` repositories you use), with `--local` you change only the configuration for the current repository.

Also check for environment variables called `GIT_<something>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your git editor set to `vi` and you see that message at all it means you *are* in vi. If you know how to use `vi`, type your message. Otherwise, change the editor to an editor you're familiar with instead.

Comment: I never realized that on the terminal title bar, 'bash' stealthily changes to 'vim'. And here I was waiting for a new window to open somewhere. Thanks!